# Read last record from database without any unique id

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to read last record from database but i don't have any unique id column. I am using Mysql workbench 6.3c

i tried this query :

```
SELECT * FROM energymetersdata where VarName='01_lab1_lsi2_kwh' 
ORDER BY VarValue desc LIMIT 1;
```

but i got the first row

Comment: Select * from table order by colname desc limit 1;

Comment: i tried this query but i didn't got the last record,why because data in my column is same for up to 10000 records

Comment: Please post what you have tried...

Comment: i have added a image please find image and help me

Comment: Have you seen the image ,in that you can find 4 fields ,that is all my table contains

Comment: Timestring would be my choice. My guess is that uniqueness is formed on the first two columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit ->is used to get the number of record you want to view from table,
'Order by desc'-> orders the column in descending order

first convert your date column date type to str_to_date

```
   SELECT *,str_to_date(timestring,'%d-%m-%Y %T')as date1 FROM energymetersdata where 
VarName='01_lab1_lsi2_kwh' ORDER BY date1 desc LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Please check this above i have changed the query

Comment: i tried this query too but i got this line-> 01_lab1_lsi2_kwh 31-01-2017 23:59:54 1.028204E+08 0 42766999932.1412
    but my last record is ->01_lab1_lsi2_kwh 02-02-2017 00:53:52 1.028204E+08 0 42768037407.6505

Comment: You can remove the condition from the query and check

Comment: Again i have made changes on my answer ...you can try based on your expected result

Comment: i tired but again same output,date1 column after execution it is showing null

Comment: Yes Date  format is wrong Now i have changed again my answer..Pleae try

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM energymetersdata where VarName='01_lab1_lsi2_kwh' 
ORDER BY TimeString desc LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try short query

```
SELECT * from energymetersdata HAVING MAX(TimeString);
```

it will return latest record which you want

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a time column called `time_ms`.  You should use this for getting the most recent value:

```
SELECT emd.*
FROM energymetersdata emd
WHERE emd.VarName = '01_lab1_lsi2_kwh' 
ORDER BY time_ms desc
LIMIT 1;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `energymetersdata(VarName, time_ms)`, which should make the query very fast.